# Filter and Map over the same array in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have the following component:

```
function Params(props) {

    const { Parameters } = useFetchParams();

    return (
        <div className='Params'>
            {
                Parameters && Parameters.map(parameter => {
                    const { Name, Value } = parameter;
                    if (Name.includes(props.filter)) {
                        return (
                            <div className='Param' key={Name}>
                                <p>{Name}</p>
                                <p>{Value}</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to only display "Parameters" that include the text I'm passing in from props. You can see I'm currently using an if statement for this, and it seems clunky. I'm wondering if it's possible to map and filter over this array at the same time.

I've tried sticking filter at the end of the map but it returns an error.

Thanks for looking

Comment: You don't really need extra loop for `.filter()` you may still use a single `.map()` that returns conditionally either your JSX or `null`/`false`/`undefined` that will get ignored on render

Comment: What error are you getting? and also have you tried console logging the value of props.filter?

Comment: @DonJuanEco as a side note, if you find you're both filtering *and* mapping an array, then you might want to use `.reduce`. It can do both of those at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Yevgen Gorbunkov suggests, what you're doing is fine, filtering before mapping is actually not faster, although it is perhaps, more readable.
But yes, it is possible to do that. Like this:

```js
function Params(props) {

    const { Parameters } = useFetchParams();

    return (
        <div className='Params'>
            {
                Parameters && Parameters.filter(parameter => parameter.Name.includes(props.filter))
                  .map(parameter => {
                    const { Name, Value } = parameter;
                    return (
                        <div className='Param' key={Name}>
                            <p>{Name}</p>
                            <p>{Value}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```